# Origin of PALMPC.ZIP "Palm PC emulator"

Tags: ms-dos, graphics, identify-this-software

The program PALMPC.COM, which is available on [an old link in the Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20000606025716/http://www.geocities.com/SiliconValley/Horizon/5463/palmpc.zip), and also on e.g. [S.U.P.E.R.](http://mizj.com/), apparently provides graphics emulation, including [interrupt 0x5F](https://fd.lod.bz/rbil/zint/index_5f.html) used by the HP/Lotus Palmtops. The program seems to have appeared publicly (mid 2000) after the Palmtops were discontinued (late 1999).

Does anybody know the origin of this program?

Answer (score 5):

This doesn’t explain the origin of the program, but it might help clarify the program’s goals.

The `PALMPC.COM` file in the widely-distributed archive is dated January 1995, so it would appear to have been written when the LX palmtops were still very much an ongoing concern.

The program is compressed using `COMPACK` 4.5; decompressing it produces a 45KiB binary which is quite straightforward. Its setup routine looks for a signature just before the interrupt 0x5F handler, “EKJG” (the author’s initials?); if it’s present, it uninstalls itself, otherwise it installs itself and terminates and stays resident, after displaying

```
Palmtop Emulator For VGA PCs
Call It Again To Remove From Memory
```

The TSR setup hooks the following interrupts:

- [interrupt 0x10](https://fd.lod.bz/rbil/zint/index_10.html), service 0xDC, “graphics cursor in video mode 6”;
- [interrupt 0x15, service 0x61](https://fd.lod.bz/rbil/interrup/bios_vendor/1561.html#1504), “set announciators position”;
- [interrupt 0x1C](https://fd.lod.bz/rbil/interrup/bios/1c.html#2481), the timer hook;
- [interrupt 0x5F](https://fd.lod.bz/rbil/zint/index_5f.html), the HP LX graphics primitives.

So the program’s purpose is *only* to implement the functions required to run programs expecting an LX-style display.

The program is unlikely to have been written by a company, since the only strings in it are the messages displayed on installation and removal, and there is no copyright statement.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140695/discussion-on-answer-by-stephen-kitt-origin-of-palmpc-zip-palm-pc-emulator).